# How to overlap two images together, create legend and keep CRS in Python(Matplotlib)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am using Python to deal with raster data(Image) and having some problems now. I hope someone could give me some advice.

I have one RGB image and one grayscale image which both have the same lines and rows(pixel) and have the same Coordinate Reference System(CRS).
[RGB Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PC0D.png)
[Grayscale Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am0vE.png)

First, I need to render the grayscale image to a colour one and create 
an automatic legend for the coloured image.

Second, I need to overlap the two images together where the RGB is at the bottom and grayscale one on the top. It could be better if two images can overlap with their CRS while I just overlapped the two images based on the same numbers of lines and rows they have.

Third, I want to save the result of the second step with the same lines and rows as the original image as well as CRS information.

I have found some ways to cope with the first step and second step in Matploblib as the code below whereas I don't think I used the right way because I got two warning while using it.
Though I can get the third step image but the image lacked CRS and was resampled.
[The resulting image that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8kPL.png)

```
import numpy as np
import gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset2 = gdal.Open('/Users/SPH_1_RGB.tif')
band_1 = dataset2.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
band_2 = dataset2.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray()
band_3 = dataset2.GetRasterBand(3).ReadAsArray()
array_RGB = np.dstack((band_1, band_2, band_3))
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.0, 0.0, 0.89, 1.0])
ax1.imshow(array_RGB)
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

# [left, bottom, width, height]
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.0, 0.0, 0.89, 1.0])
ax2.set_title('Chlorophyll_a')
dataset = gdal.Open('/Users/SPH_1_Grayscale.tif')
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
array0 = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, band.XSize, band.YSize)
array_Gray = np.ma.masked_where(array0 == 0.0, array0)
im = ax2.imshow(array_Gray, interpolation='nearest', cmap='jet')

cbaxes = fig.add_axes([0.9, 0.25, 0.02, 0.5])
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, orientation="vertical", cax=cbaxes)
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
plt.savefig('/Users/SPH_1_Overlap.jpg', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

I got two warnings:

1. Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
   "Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes "
2. UserWarning: Use the colorbar set_ticks() method instead.
   warnings.warn("Use the colorbar set_ticks() method instead.")

My questions are:

1. Is there a better way to complete this work and how to avoid the two warnings?
2. How to save the image in Matplotlib without resampling and keep CRS.

Comment: Avoid warnings: (a) Add a label to the axes as the warning suggests, `fig.add_axes([...], label="first axes")` same for the second one. (b) Instead of `plt.xticks(())` use `ax1.set_xticks([])`, same for ax2.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  Thanks, your advice solved the warning problems.